# Introduction to Java Graphics Libraries

Tags: java, graphics, visualization

I just got into information-visualization and scientific-visualization and have been using Piccolo and a little with JFreeChart. I am trying to find a few new libraries that I can start using. I am looking specifically for libraries that involve multi-dimensional visualization and map overlaying (something like open-layers), but would be open to get exposure to any graphics libraries.

Comment: For JVM-based graphics see also [http://waterloo.sourceforge.net](http://waterloo.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 7):

You may want to look at [Processing](http://processing.org/) - a data visualisation environment and language written in Java.

Comment: Processing runs as applet. It is near impossible to get it out of the applet. Thus if you ever plan to use your visualization in another way, dont use Processing (even though else its an awesome library).

Comment: If you hit Ctrl+Shift+E, it exports as an application, not an applet

Comment: How would you describe the learning curve and how robust of a library is it?

Comment: The Processing website has a wealth of information, and there are books on it (by publishers like OReilly). I've not used it much, but I think the resources available should make it straightforward to pick up.

Answer (score 4):

You might also want to consider [**R**](http://www.r-project.org), which as very extensive graphic capabilities and is used extensively in academic research and places like the NY Times.  It would require you to learn a new syntax, but it is very hard to beat for scientific visualizations, and it can easily be [called from Java using **JRI**](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/).

Here are a few resources:

- [R Graph Gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/) contains a large number of R graphics along with the code that used to create them (there's also the related [R Movie Gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/movies/)).
- Definitely look at [the Graphics view on **CRAN**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Graphics.html), which includes an extensive list of packages for graphics in R (ranging from [iPlots: interactive graphics for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iplots/index.html) to [rggobi which is an interface to ggobi](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rggobi/index.html)).

Also, while this isn't R specific, [the gallery of data visualization is worth looking at](http://www.math.yorku.ca/SCS/Gallery/).

Comment: Hey thanks alot for this answer. I only saw it after the bounty but I really like it. Best I can give you is the upvote

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with pure Java, look at [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) for graph visualization.

Comment: Actually Prefuse is designed for Data visualization, but it has some special support for graphs

Answer (score 1):

There is a few [java graphic libraries available here](http://www.mathtools.net/Java/Graphics_and_Visualization/)

Answer (score 1):

[JMathTool](http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php) may be interesting. It will allow you to do simple 3D graphs quickly, however it isn't designed to handle more complicated visualisations.

Comment: This looks like fun, I will have to look into it a little bit

Answer (score 1):

The combination that I think I will be using is [JMathPlot](http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php?id=jmathplot:tutorial) (similar to matlab) for visualizing scientific data and using [JOGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL) for visualizing informational data

Answer (score 0):

QuickDraw, written by University of Calgary professors Schock and Stephenson, is a great simple tool for graphics visualisation. Free for personal and non-commercial use.

http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/QuickDraw/

Comment: It's also language-independent via piping. Sexy.